# issues with Java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Let's say I have a data set of

```
Person    Friend
--------------------
FriendA   FriendB
FriendB   FriendC
```

I want to traverse through the list and get the ultimate friend a file. I have tried this so far, it does not work, I get a stack overflow error when I try anything else.

```
public class Pair {

public String key;
public String value;

public Pair(String key, String value)
   {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }
}



import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class OpenFile 
{

public static String checkFriend (String name, final ArrayList<Pair> pair)
{
    String new_friend_name = null;

    for (Pair p : pair)
    {
        if (p.key == name)
        {
            new_friend_name = (String) p.value;
        }
    }

    return new_friend_name;
}

public static String getUltimateFriend(String name, final ArrayList<Pair> pair)
{
    String friend = null;

    if (checkFriend(name, pair) == null) return name;
    while (checkFriend(name, pair) != null)
    {
        friend = checkFriend(name, pair);
    }

    return friend;
    //return new_friend_name;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Files\\Desktop\\Java Programs\\data\\data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] var = null;
    ArrayList<Pair> pair = new ArrayList<Pair>();

    System.out.println("my pair output from a loop");
    for (Pair p : pair)
    {
        System.out.println(p.key + " is friends with " + getUltimateFriend(p.key,pair));    
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();


}
```

}

> I tried recursion, but I am getting StackOverflow error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the full stack trace for the exception? I wouldn't expect this to throw a StackOverflow, since it isn't actually recursive.

Comment: I did change it from recursion. This is the non-recursive version

Comment: You should make that clearer. If the code above isn't recursive, then the entire part of the question about recursion and the stack overflow is irrelevant. What's even your question then?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use recursion because nowhere does a method call itself.
I guess your problem is in your loop:

```
while (checkFriend(name, pair) != null)
{
    friend = checkFriend(name, pair);
}
```

Here you are doing the same thing endlessly.

Comment: If you had similar logic in the recursive version, that's probably why you got a stack overflow error - the recursion became infinite.